# Using python social auth to register users by access token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I found this snippet of code that helps me authenticate a user and then create a rest_framework token for them. The client I am using is a native android app and I will get the access token from the client side and post it to django in the ObtainAuth class.
Here is the code for the server side.

```
@psa('social:complete')     
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    backend = request.strategy.backend
    # Split by spaces and get the array
    auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

    if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b'token':
        msg = 'No token header provided.'
        return msg

    if len(auth) == 1:
        msg = 'Invalid token header. No credentials provided.'
        return msg

    access_token = auth[1]

    user = backend.do_auth(access_token)

    return user     



class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
      model = Token
      serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
      parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
      renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)


      def post(self,request):
           serializer = self.serializer_class(data= request.DATA)

        if backend == 'auth':  
           if serializer.is_valid:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.object['user'])
                if token:
                     return Response({'token': token.key})
                else:    
                     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
           else:

                user = register_by_access_token(request, backend)

                if user and user.is_active:
                     token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                return Response({'id': user.id, 'email': user.email, 'firstname': user.first_name, 'userRole': 'user', 'token': token.key})
```

The register_by_access_token method will get the facebook access token and then create a user with the rest_framework.It takes a request and the backend to be used e.g 'facebook'.

If a user  logs in with my backend then the backend is 'auth' and it uses the normal process of retrieving the email and password and then giving me a token to use.As detailed [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication)

My question is how do I post the authentication backend be it 'facebook' or 'auth' so that I can receive the token?

What I've tried.
I have tried sending the backend type  ('facebook' or 'auth') with the access token but I get an error that the method takes 3 arguments and I've only provided 2. 
I've tried making the url take a backend like this:

```
url(r'^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$',views.ObtainAuthToken.as_view())
```

then sending the access token to a url like this mysite.com:8000/login/facebook.

None of these work and I don't have much expereience with psa  or django to know how to pass this parameter.

How do I send which backend to use so that it can be accepted by the method? If anyone has ever had this use case please help me out.

Comment: Did you try to define the ``post`` method to be ``def post(self, request, backend)`` when using the ``^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$`` URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to my understanding social login requires a access token , so when you are login with facebook when you call 'mysite.com:8000/login/facebook' it is expecting a access token,

for my project i defined my urls as 'url(r'^login/(?P[^/]+)/$',register_by_access_token,name='register_by_access_token')',with the token i am sending it completes the login, for facebook i send backend as 'facebook' for google i send backend as 'google-oauth2' but both the case i am sending a token given my respective backend, when you are not using a third party backend you wont get the token and the login expects that.

so my suggestion is if you are going with auth use normal login post, not the same URL.